# php file uploads over 200mb

Tags: php, file-upload, reliability

after changing the max file size, session times, and post max size is it wise to use php to upload files larger than 200mb? reliable? (and this is ignoring whether a client connection is maintained)

edit: done through http not ftp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No problem.

We have an up-/downloads site at work so that customers can send print data. And these files can get pretty big.

Comment: does your site transfer data over http?

Comment: @Dacto: I've never seen an ftp server written in PHP. Would be fun, though. Of course it's http. It's a PHP question.

Comment: well idk, someone could possibly send data through ftp protocol via php...hehe idk, Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think that major issue is client's browser stability, and client's connection. It's pretty hard to transmit that much of data without any accident...